# Delete access based on checkbox value

Tags: apex, crud

I have a requirement where I would like to disable Delete permission on records for Profile ABC based on a checkbox in the record. Is there any possibility of achieving this requirement without using code in salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

In case if code is not really an option, then one of the options could be to make a new custom field - checkbox, add a validation rule to prevent the record to have this checkbox to be set to true in case if there is profile match and other input.

Then create before delete flow, which would do an update for record being deleted and check newly created checkbox to true.

Downsides to the approach would be:

- Unnecessary update operation, can be critical in case of custom integrations etc.
- Necessity to have a custom checkbox field only for this purpose.
- Delete button will still appear on a record.